# Post a text request in Casablanca (C++ REST SDK)

Tags: visual-c++, httpclient, casablanca

I am writing a client side code in Visual C++ 2012 using C++ Rest SDK (codename "Casablanca").
I have a client created and wish to POST a text string to the server. However, when I send the following code, it is compiling but not sending sending the request.
When I remove everything after "methods::POST" and send a blank post request, then it is sent and received by the server.
Can you please guide me where the problem is. The documentation related to this function is available on [Casablanca Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj948546.aspx).

```
pplx::task<http_response>resp = client.request(methods::POST,L"",L"This is the random text that I wish to send", L"text/plain");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the usage you give here looks correct. 
Is your Casablanca the latest version ? Please check that out from here : http://casablanca.codeplex.com/
If you are sure your measurement is accurate, you may want to create a minimal repro and file a bug here : http://casablanca.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, all my POSTs was arriving in blank on server , after a few hours work above it, i found a possible solution.
I changed the default content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and I started to pass the values like this Example `data=text1&data2=text2`

```
client.request(methods::POST,L"",L"data=text1&data2=text2", L"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Answer (score 0):

The body parameter must be a json::value.

Comment: Can't a normal text be sent ? Also, when I try to create the json::value using -json::value obj;
  obj[L"key1"] = json::value::string(U("str"));
The code hangs there itself only; it doesn't proceed further. I got this code from [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/02/26/the-c-rest-sdk-quot-casablanca-quot.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet so I have to put my thoughts in an answer. I solved this problem like this: There is an overload of the request method that takes as a parameter the content type so that you do not have to change the code.

```
m_client->request(methods::POST, L"/statuses/update.json?" + url_encode(data),L"",L"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Obviously you would have to implement the url_encode method but that is not difficult. There is a pretty good implementation in "Cassablanca". A search on this site will alos turn up some good examples.